# MySQL: Order of query based on before rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a database structure like this:

• `Insured` table

```
+-----------+--------------+-----+
| InsuredID |         Name | ... |
+-----------+--------------+-----+
|         1 |     John Doe | ... |
|         2 |   Bill Gates | ... |
|         3 |   Steve Jobs | ... |
+-----------+--------------+-----+
```

• `Accompany` table

```
+-------------+-----------+---------------+-----+
| AccompanyID | InsuredID |          Name | ... |
+-------------+-----------+---------------+-----+
|           1 |         1 |    Joanna Doe | ... |
|           2 |         1 |    Johnny Doe | ... |
|           3 |         3 | Steve Ballmer | ... |
+-------------+-----------+---------------+-----+
```

How can I have this result:

```
+----------------+-----+
|           Name | ... |
+----------------+-----+
|       John Doe | ... |
|     Joanna Doe | ... |
|     Johnny Doe | ... |
|     Bill Gates | ... |
|     Steve Jobs | ... |
|  Steve Ballmer | ... |
+----------------+-----+
```

How can I make the order of the query to be - `Insured` then `Accompany`'s where the `Accompany.InsuredID` is equivalent to the `Insured.InsuredID` before the `Accompany`. It should be ordered like this:

1. John Doe (Insured) `InsuredID = 1`
2. Joanna Doe (Accompany) `InsuredID = 1`
3. Johnny Doe (Accompany) `InsuredID = 1`
4. Bill Gates (Insured) `InsuredID = 2`
5. Steve Jobs (Insured) `InsuredID = 3`
6. Steve Balmer (Accompany) `InsuredID = 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select name
from (
 select insuredid, name, 0 ins
 from insured
 union all
 select insuredid, name, 1 ins
 from  accompany) isq
order by insuredid, ins
```

Basically insert a fake column to identify what table the lines are coming from, then sort by `insuredid`, then by our arbitrary table number.

Comment: Brilliant, never thought of that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM (SELECT NAme,.... FROM Insured
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Name,.... FROM Accompany)
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: you missed an alias for the inner view.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, something like this:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM (
      SELECT InsuredID, Name FROM Insured 
      UNION 
      SELECT InsuredID, Name FROM Accompany
     ) AS t
ORDER BY InsuredID
```